# How can I create a table in MySql?

Tags: c#, mysql, json, database

I have this JSON file och I am trying to create a table that contains those informations.

```
{
    "name": "John Smith",
    "sku": "20223",
    "shipTo": {
        "name": "Jane Smith",
        "address": "123 Maple Street",
        "city": "Pretendville",
        "state": "NY",
        "zip": "12345"
    },
    "billTo": {
        "name": "John Smith",
        "address": "123 Maple Street",
        "city": "Pretendville",
        "state": "NY",
        "zip": "12345"
    }
}
```

That what I tried to do in mysql database

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
        name VARCHAR(200),
        sku VARCHAR(200),
        shipTo // what type should I use to get shipTo data ie name, address, city ...?
        billTo // same thing here.
        );
```

Comment: Does shown JSON is complete pattern, and no additional attributes may occur in another JSON? Does `name` in root, shipTo and billTo is always the same? Does address data in shipTo and billTo is always the same? You need at least 2 tables for to store this data in normalized form (optimal - maybe up to 6 tables). Of course you may store this JSON as-is in one column of JSON type.. but any data processing will be problematic in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MySQL JSON data type. Please head onto [this link](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-json/) for a well explained example.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table_name (
>     ...
>     json_column_name JSON,
>     ... 
> );
> ```

Hope I got your question right.